# Installing Ubuntu 14.04.2 to a Windows XP machine

Tags: 14.04

I installed Ubuntu on a Windows XP machine but can't open or run it because Windows has to "know what program created it". What's my next step? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds as if you used wubi ? In that case reboot and select Ubuntu from the boot menu (grub)

Comment: Please don't use wubi any more!  It's deprecated!  Use [this Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) instead!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rebooting the machine?

What usually happens (if it's a dual boot install) is when you reboot your machine, the computer asks which operating system do you want to use.

I'm aware Ubuntu has a possible setting to run itself as a program from inside of Windows, but I haven't tried that myself.

Comment: I moved Ubuntu to an external hard drive, rebooted and hit f9 which gives me a choice of reboot files. USB port (where the external drive is) was one choice and I made it. It then goes to a Windows xp reboot or restore. Guess I need another option.

Comment: There's too many things that might need to change in your boot scripts for that to 'just work' after moving Ubuntu.

Comment: There's too many things that might need to change in your boot scripts for that to 'just work' after moving Ubuntu. Your drive mappings/mount points will probably be all wrong, the boot loader will try and find 'something' in Ubuntu - can't see it and so drop back to Windows where it can find 'something'. You should probably install to the External drive from the start, but it would only work on that machine and I'm not sure the USB connection will be consistent on every boot (you might change ports for example). Plus your USB connection will be slow compared to an internal Drive